# Create live stream from iPhone camera and host it on a web page

Tags: iphone, node.js, bash, jailbreak

**TL;DR**

How can I access a video stream from an iPhone camera via the iPhone's command line? Can I do this with node.js or a bash script?

**Longer Version**

I have a very hacky project idea in mind that involves generating a live video feed from an iPhone camera. I am jailbroken and have node.js installed on my iphone. I would like to pass a live video stream from my camera to my node.js application that will display the video feed on a web page. The node.js server is located on my iphone. I would like to keep the whole solution on my iphone, meaning the only server involved should be my node server on the iPhone. Can I access the camera directly through node.js (doubtful)? Can I access the camera via a bash script on my phone (seems more likely)? I'm looking for a solution that doesn't force me to create an IOS application (like I said, hacky). The reason I don't want to create an iPhone app is because I would ultimately like to build my own custom hardware for this task after I've ironed out the software involved. The iphone has a camera and mic built in, and has slightly lower cpu power than I plan on using, so I feel it will be a good platform to prototype my software on. I plan on porting this project to hardware built off of a hackberry (running linux) once I have the software working on an iphone.

There are posts (somewhat) like this floating around, but I believe they are all Objective-C solutions. I know nothing about objective-C, and don't plan on using Objective-C in later iterations of my project, so I'd like to avoid Objective-C based solutions (if possible). If you think it is not possible without Objective-C, and you have an Objective-C solution in mind, I wouldn't mind hearing your answer.

**Edit**
Can I access safari from the iPhone command line? I know I can access the iPhone camera from a web page, so could I programmatically navigate my phone to a webpage that accesses its camera, start the feed from there, and pass that feed into my node.js app?

Answer (score 1):

use RED5 ang ffmpeg to create streamer server then you can write simple PHP class to work as bridge between IPhone and your server, I advice you to use Swift on your IPhone App Part, hopefully this help you. the following may be help you too https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-red5-on-ubuntu-12-10

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this isn't quite what I'm looking for. PHP is probably my best language, but I'm trying to avoid it for this project for efficiency reasons. I will probably write the bridge in Node.js if a bridge is needed (I know it probably will be). I would also like to try and avoid Java as well for the same reason I'm avoiding PHP.  I don't really plan on making an iPhone App, at least not until I have a working project. If I do write an iPhone App, it will likely be only for receiving the live video feed.

Comment: My end goal isn't to steam video between iPhones, but to stream video from a mini server with a cam and mic to a website that the user can access from any device. Thank you for the ffmpeg suggestion. I will more than likely end up using that technology.

Comment: @AustinWilliams, ffmpeg supports AVFoundation as input device and can record video into a file https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Webcam#AVFoundation What you could do is record your video into two or more files of, lets say, 10 seconds. When you done recording the last one your overwrite the first one and so on - works like a ring buffer. Your server will serve the files which are already done recording. So it willl be live feed but with some fixed delay. That's very simple solution that will probably work without any complicated real-time camera feed encoding and streaming.

Comment: @AustinWilliams, and no, you can't acess camera feed through safari. You can only use it to capture photo or video and then save it.

Comment: @creker, I thought that might be the case about accessing via safari. Thanks for the ring buffer idea. I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: Just a thought, how practical/possible/time delayed would it be to access via safari, record 5 seconds, save and send in one thread, then start a second thread at the 3 second mark, stitch the recordings together, and repeat this process to create a delayed feed that appears to be somewhat live? If going a route like this, could I crawl the website from my phone in a way that allowed me to access the web page from my phones CLI and access my phones camera this way?